# The remote server returned an error: (401)Unauthorized when I try to connect to Microsoft Exchange Server

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

Getting The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401)Unauthorized when I try to connect to Microsoft Exchange Server
The error message I am getting is :

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401)Unauthorized
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:74)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:158)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.findItems(ExchangeService.java:981)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.findItems(ExchangeService.java:1024)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.findItems(ExchangeService.java:1100)
Caused by: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401)Unauthorized
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:644)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:62)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.http.HttpErrorException: The remote server returned an error: (401)Unauthorized
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.getEwsHttpWebResponse(ServiceRequestBase.java:723)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:639)
    ... 7 more
```

The code snippet which I have been using is:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Users\\vermad\\Downloads\\Softz\\jssecacerts");
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("username.domain.com","password");
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.setUrl(new URI("https:/domain/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));
ItemView view = new ItemView (5);
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);
for(Item item : findResults.getItems()){
    item.load(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.MimeContent));
    System.out.println("id==========" + item.getId());
}
```

Comment: Hi Dharmesh, Did you find the reason for this error and how did you fix it.

Comment: why this question is voted 3 when there is no solution that would help anyone looking at this issue?